# How can I safety unwrap an optional with a default value using `coalescing unwrapping` - Not workig - Swift

Tags: swift, option-type, unwrap

How can I safety unwrap the first optional item from `arrayOfStrings` to get just the `pounds` with a default value of 0 using `coalescing unwrapping`?

Based on the code below, what I want is to be able to get the `5` but if this would be empty assign 0 as the default value, for instance if the `measurement` is `"lb. 8oz."` I want `pounds` to get the value of 0.

In the following example, I do get `5` but it crashes if I change `measurement` from `"5lb. 8oz."` to `"lb. 8oz."`

```
let measurement = "5lb. 8oz."

let arrayOfStrings:[String] = measurement.components(separatedBy: "l")
print("Array of Strings: \(arrayOfStrings)") //Output: Array of Strings: ["5", "b. 8oz."]

let pounds = Double(arrayOfStrings[0] ?? "0") 
print("Pounds \(pounds!)") //Output: Pounds 5.0
```

**Error**: When changing `measurement` to `"lb. 8oz."`

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

FYI - I'm looking for a single line solution, I know how to do it using `if let` or `guard`.

Comment: If you are not opposed to using Foundation then a simple `let pounds = (measurement as NSString).doubleValue` does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unwrap the access of the array *and* the conversion to Double

```
let pounds = Double(arrayOfStrings.first ?? "0") ?? 0.0
```

Comment: I get error `let pounds = Double(arrayOfStrings.first ?? "0") ?? 0.0` Error: ` error: cannot force unwrap valueof non-optional type 'Double'`

Comment: @fs_tigre Are you sure that error refers to that line? `pounds` is no longer optional with this solution so you can't unwrap it any more

Comment: Oops, no it was referring to `print("Pounds \(pounds!)")`, removed `!` and it worked.

Comment: Is this what is referred to `optional chaining`?

Comment: @fs_tigre No that is when you have an optional variable/property that you ar calling a property or method on. `var array: [String]?; array?.count`

Comment: @fs_tigre, no this is not *optional chaining*.  Optional chaining is when you place a single `?` after an optional and then proceed to access a member or call a function on it.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27734933/1630618) for examples of *optional chaining*.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - Quick question. Why is that your solution only works if I use `.first ?? "0"` but it doesn't work if I change it to  `[0] ?? "0"`? What if I wanted to extract the second item from the array  `[1] ?? "0"`?

Comment: @fs_tigre If the array is empty .first will return nil but [0] will crash. If you want to access the array like that, [0], [1] etc, you better check the length of the array first. Also since [0] is not optional it is pointless to do `[0] ?? "0"` because the `?? "0"` part will never be executed

Answer (score 1):

```
let pounds = Double(arrayOfStrings[0]) ?? 0.0
print("Pounds \(pounds)")
```

Works for me.

Comment: It indeed does work... I thought I tried it before and it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: This will work fine as long as the array isn't empty

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. Infact using .first than indexing [0] would be better.